# If statement in sql server not recognizing temp table field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #CategoriesTable
(
   CategoryId INT,
   HasAssessment BIT,
   IsScorm BIT, 
   IsExternal BIT,
   ExternalLink varchar(256), 
   SingleArtifact BIT, 
   ScormModuleUrl varchar(256),
   WindowHeight varchar(256), 
   WindowWidth varchar(256),
   DateTimeCreated date,
   HintText nvarchar(256),
   UserId INT
)

select ct.HasAssessment from #CategoriesTable ct
  where UserId = @UserId  
IF (ct.HasAssessment = 1)
BEGIN
  UPDATE #CategoriesTable SET HintText = 'With Assessment'
END    
else
BEGIN
 UPDATE #CategoriesTable SET HintText = 'With No Assessment'    
END      

SELECT *
  FROM #CategoriesTable
```

I get the following error: The multi-part identifier "ct.HasAssessment" could not be bound.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need an IF statement. The update can be done entirely through standard SQL.

```
UPDATE #CategoriesTable
SET    HintText = CASE WHEN HasAssessment = 1 
                       THEN 'With Assessment' 
                       ELSE 'With No Assessment' 
                  END 
WHERE  UserID = @UserID
```

If you do wish to use the `IF`statement *(not advisable)*, you need to declare a variable to hold the result of your select statement and use this variable in the `IF`statement.

Note that the select statement in this case should only ever return one result, yet another reason to perform the update entirely in SQL.